# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$, $a_k=\frac{1}{k}\sin(\frac{1}{k})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to use the limit comparison test to test for convergence but I've got different results depending on what I use as my $b_k$

If I use $b_k=\frac{1}{k^{2}}$, I have $\frac{a_k}{b_k}\to 1$
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$ converges, so $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ will also converge

But if I use $b_k=\sin\frac{1}{k}$, $\frac{a_k}{b_k}\to 0$.
And here, $b_k$ diverges, $a_k$ must diverge also...

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}=0$ and $b_k$ converges, then so does $a_k$. If $a_k$ diverges, then so does $b_k$. But in your case the test is inconclusive. So you have no contradiction.

Comment: Ok, that clears things up a lot.  I didn't realise that the limit tending to 0 was a special case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your series converges by your first example. The second one doesn't work as the limit is zero, and it must be *greater* than zero and less than infinity.